# Import class in eclipse's display view

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, view

I need to capture an object inside my application to analise its values. So while debbuging, I'm trying to convert it to json using display tab view.
But when I've executed the import code, I got an error:

```
Sintax error on token "import", assert expected.
```

Here is what I'm trying to execute in display's view:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
OBJECT_MAPPER.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();

String json = OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(cart);
System.out.println(json);
```

Anyone knows how to import this class?

(Actually, I did it. But I would like to have a generic code in order to not have to modify my class code just to capture its json.)

Comment: try using the full qualified class name instead of the import. Like `org.codehouse.jackson.map.Objectmapper mapper = new org.codehouse.jackson.map.ObjectMapper()`

Comment: import statements are for the compiler. They can not be executed like other statements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the import. Use FQN (Full qualified name)

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
OBJECT_MAPPER.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();

String json = OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(cart);
System.out.println(json);
```

It should work

Comment: It is what we end up doing.  But it doesn't answer to the question "how to import this class?".  Depending on the code, if you need to look up the full qualified name of every class and edit your code fragment, it is tedious and error prone.  Especially for a one-time execution.  I would be interested in a way to actually import all the needed classes instead.

Comment: Just wanted to note that you can Ctrl+Space within the name of the class and get its FQN from autocomplete.